# Is it appropriate (RESTful) to have a resource that is an aggregation of another resource?

Tags: rest

Let's say you have a resource `KeyValuePair`

```
type KeyValuePair = {
   id: string; 
   key: string; 
   value: unknown; 
}
```

and we can CRUD this resource via a `/keyvaluepairs` endpoint.

Now - lets we have some `Widget` resource

```
type Widget = {
    id: string; 
    foo: string; 
    bar: number;  
}
```

Now, for some, let's assume good, reason, in the background we're going to be storing this resource as a series of KeyValuePairs.

eg, in the database the resource

```
{
   id: "1", 
   foo: "foobyfoo", 
   bar: 123
}
```

Would be stored as:

```
{
    id: "some-random-id-1", 
    key: "WIDGET-1-ID", 
    value: "1",
}, 
{
    id: "some-random-id-2", 
    key: "WIDGET-1-FOO", 
    value: "foobyfoo",
}, 
{
    id: "some-random-id-3", 
    key: "WIDGET-1-BAR", 
    value: 123,
}
```

The question is, would CRUDing the `Widget` resource via a `/widgets` endpoint be appropriate?

ie.

GET /widget/1

would return the object:

```
{
   id: "1", 
   foo: "foobyfoo", 
   bar: 123
}
```

But what the backend has actually done is retrieved those keyvaluepairs and created the object from them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> would CRUDing the Widget resource via a /widgets endpoint be appropriate?

Yes, of course.

> But what the backend has actually done is retrieved those keyvaluepairs and created the object from them

So what? that's just an implementation detail.  There's no reason that your *resource model* needs a 1:1 correspondence with your *data model*.

Part of the point of REST is that general purpose clients can work with the resource abstraction, without needing to know anything about how the origin server is actually storing information.